# Maximize ratio of logarithms

Tags: optimization, logarithms

How can one maximize the ratio of two logarithms $ \frac{\log{f(x)}}{\log{g(x)}}$ where the argument to each logarithm is the (positive) ratio of two first-degree polynomials? I have tried differentiating and solving for $ x $ but became caught in a quagmire of logarithms. Are there any simplifications or transformations that can be applied that will preserve maxima or zeros of the derivative?

For discussion, here's a complete example - selecting the amount of fuel to carry to maximize the stage specific impulse of an ideal rocket described by the [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

$$ \frac{\log{\frac{(\alpha+1)x + \beta}{\alpha x+\beta}}}{\log{\frac{(\alpha + 1)x+\beta}{\beta-\gamma}}} $$

$ \alpha $, $ \beta $, and $ \beta - \gamma $ are all positive. $ \alpha $ is the mass of storage to contain one unit of fuel, $ \beta $ is the combined mass of the payload and rocket engine, and $ \gamma $ is the mass of the rocket engine alone.

Comment: A way to avoid so much mire is to use the fact that $\log\frac{a}{b}=\log a-\log b$.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt. Do you think that this would simplify the problem for the question ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici No, indeed this form is probably the simplest way to write it, but my thinking was that getting rid of quotients can help cut down on the messiness of derivatives

Comment: Could you give me a set of values for $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ ?

Comment: The derivative, both in the general case and in the particular example, has the variable $x$ both inside and outside transcendental functions in an essential way (e.g., one cannot remove all instances of one or the other by multiplying through), so probably there is no closed-form solution in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: As Travis commented, there is more than likely no closed form for the solution. If $\alpha x$ is small when compared to $\beta$, may be an approximate solution could be obtained. This is what I wanted to check when asking you for some values of the constants.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici A possible set of values would be $ \alpha = 1/8, \beta = 1.5, \gamma = .5 $. This is maximized when $ x \approx 10 $ or $ \alpha x \approx 1.25 $, which is not small compared to $ \beta $.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt That relation - that logarithms turn multiples into differences - is actually the reason why the quantity appears this way. The top quantity of the ratio is $\Delta v$, the velocity change a rocket can undergo. A linear increase in $\Delta v$ is expected to correspond to an exponential increase in the total mass of the rocket, $(\alpha + 1)x+\beta$. The optimization question is then: given a rocket and payload, how much $\Delta v$ can we get per multiple of the mass. How the conversion from exponential to linear growth is written doesn't change the messiness of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this really answers the intended question; I'm just leaving it here for reference.

The derivative of $\log f(x)/\log g(x)$ is zero when
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)\log f(x)}=\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)\log g(x)}.$$
When you have $f(x)=a(x)/b(x)$ and $g(x)=c(x)/d(x)$, this becomes
$$\frac{a'(x)/a(x) - b'(x)/b(x)}{\log a(x) - \log b(x)}=\frac{c'(x)/c(x) - d'(x)/d(x)}{\log c(x) - \log d(x)}.$$
When $a(x)$, $b(x)$, $c(x)$, and $d(x)$ are first-degree polynomials, the derivatives in the above expression become constants, but the expression doesn't simplify much after that.